# Install ROS on CentOS 6

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'd like to install ROS on our department HPC cluster.
The cluster OS is CentOS 6.4.

```
$ uname -rms
Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 x86_64

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Could anybody please tell me

1. what packages (source or binaries) to download
2. the install procedure

Thank you and best regards.
Robi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119716/install-ros-on-centos-6/) by [Robi](https://answers.ros.org/users/11026/robi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-01-21**:
Also, it is very likely many people did not see this question due to the tags you used, I'll try to improve my tag filter, as I don't know what other tags you would have put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the others have said, this page has everything you need:

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source

You will have to find the CentOS equivalents to the things in the first paragraph. @Dirk Thomas just updated the above page with instructions about how to install the prerequisites on non-Ubuntu OS's.

I understand your want for the links to the tarballs, but some of these prerequisites are not published by us (Make, CMake, compiler, etc...) and the others are distributed as build tools, if you want their sources, you can simply treat them as normal Python packages. That means installed via pip, the instructions for this are now in the wiki page, and the sources obtainable from pypi.python.org, e.g. `rosdep` is installed with `[sudo] pip install rosdep` and the source can be located here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rosdep

Once you have moved pass the prerequisites then comes the source code for the ROS packages and the instructions on the above wiki page tell you exactly how to get the source code via tarballs.

Since the ROS ecosystem is very large (hundreds of packages) we provide the `rosinstall_generator` tool to figure out what tar balls you need. For example, to get all of the source for `roscpp`, this command would be used:

```
% rosinstall_generator --deps --tar --rosdistro hydro roscpp
- tar:
    local-name: catkin
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/catkin-release/archive/release/hydro/catkin/0.5.79-0.tar.gz
    version: catkin-release-release-hydro-catkin-0.5.79-0
- tar:
    local-name: console_bridge
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/console_bridge-release/archive/release/hydro/console_bridge/0.2.4-1.tar.gz
    version: console_bridge-release-release-hydro-console_bridge-0.2.4-1
- tar:
    local-name: cpp_common
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release/archive/release/hydro/cpp_common/0.3.17-0.tar.gz
    version: roscpp_core-release-release-hydro-cpp_common-0.3.17-0
- tar:
    local-name: gencpp
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/gencpp-release/archive/release/hydro/gencpp/0.4.15-0.tar.gz
    version: gencpp-release-release-hydro-gencpp-0.4.15-0
- tar:
    local-name: genlisp
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/genlisp-release/archive/release/hydro/genlisp/0.4.12-0.tar.gz
    version: genlisp-release-release-hydro-genlisp-0.4.12-0
- tar:
    local-name: genmsg
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release/archive/release/hydro/genmsg/0.4.24-0.tar.gz
    version: genmsg-release-release-hydro-genmsg-0.4.24-0
- tar:
    local-name: genpy
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/genpy-release/archive/release/hydro/genpy/0.4.15-0.tar.gz
    version: genpy-release-release-hydro-genpy-0.4.15-0
- tar:
    local-name: message_generation
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/message_generation-release/archive/release/hydro/message_generation/0.2.10-0.tar.gz
    version: message_generation-release-release-hydro-message_generation-0.2.10-0
- tar:
    local-name: message_runtime
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/message_runtime-release/archive/release/hydro/message_runtime/0.4.12-0.tar.gz
    version: message_runtime-release-release-hydro-message_runtime-0.4.12-0
- tar:
    local-name: rosconsole
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/hydro/rosconsole/1.9.53-0.tar.gz
    version: ros_comm-release-release-hydro-rosconsole-1.9.53-0
- tar:
    local-name: roscpp
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/hydro/roscpp/1.9.53-0.tar.gz
    version: ros_comm-release-release-hydro-roscpp-1.9.53-0
- tar:
    local-name: roscpp_serialization
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release/archive/release/hydro/roscpp_serialization/0.3.17-0.tar.gz
    version: roscpp_core-release-release-hydro-roscpp_serialization-0.3.17-0
- tar:
    local-name: roscpp_traits
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release/archive/release/hydro/roscpp_traits/0.3.17-0.tar.gz
    version: roscpp_core-release-release-hydro-roscpp_traits-0.3.17-0
- tar:
    local-name: rosgraph_msgs
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/hydro/rosgraph_msgs/1.9.53-0.tar.gz
    version: ros_comm-release-release-hydro-rosgraph_msgs-1.9.53-0
- tar:
    local-name: roslang
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/hydro/roslang/1.10.9-0.tar.gz
    version: ros-release-release-hydro-roslang-1.10.9-0
- tar:
    local-name: roslib
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/hydro/roslib/1.10.9-0.tar.gz
    version: ros-release-release-hydro-roslib-1.10.9-0
- tar:
    local-name: rospack
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/rospack-release/archive/release/hydro/rospack/2.1.22-0.tar.gz
    version: rospack-release-release-hydro-rospack-2.1.22-0
- tar:
    local-name: rostime
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/roscpp_core-release/archive/release/hydro/rostime/0.3.17-0.tar.gz
    version: roscpp_core-release-release-hydro-rostime-0.3.17-0
- tar:
    local-name: rosunit
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros-release/archive/release/hydro/rosunit/1.10.9-0.tar.gz
    version: ros-release-release-hydro-rosunit-1.10.9-0
- tar:
    local-name: std_msgs
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/std_msgs-release/archive/release/hydro/std_msgs/0.5.8-0.tar.gz
    version: std_msgs-release-release-hydro-std_msgs-0.5.8-0
- tar:
    local-name: xmlrpcpp
    uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release/archive/release/hydro/xmlrpcpp/1.9.53-0.tar.gz
    version: ros_comm-release-release-hydro-xmlrpcpp-1.9.53-0
```

The output is YAML which can be used with our `wstool` in order to fetch all of the tar balls for you. After than you can do what ever you need with the source, but I recommend you follow the above wiki once you get past the prerequisites I think you will find it pretty generic.

**EDIT:** Also, ignore the `<a...>` tags in the YAML above, that is a rendering bug with askbot... Ticketed for a long time here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/55

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

ROS is highly distributed across a large number of repositories since it is largely community-sourced, so there is no single repository we can point you to. The core tools are at: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm and that's a good place to start. Then, search for each package you need and get its source. Those core tools are enough for message passing and such. If you need help finding a specific package (ie if your using your HPC for map building you would need to get https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping and also find all of its dependencies) then let us know and we can try to help find a source.

On the topic of being heavily tied to Ubuntu: ROS will build on any linux system (in theory), the problem is that the dependency tree is so huge that it is generally not practical to install *everything* from source. For instance, if you wanted to install rviz then you'd need (among other things) PCL, and just building the entire PCL dependency tree entirely from source is a nightmare (in my experience). So package managers simplify everything by allowing the community to move forward with development without worrying about spending literally days finding and building huge dependency trees.

Hope this helps,
Tim Sweet

**Edit:**

To address your second question of how to build ROS: you'll need catkin (and more specifically: [catkin_make_isolated](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0134.html) ) from https://github.com/ros/catkin which can be used to build everything, assuming you have already solved the dependency tree problem.

---

Originally posted by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) with karma: 267 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS source is distributed across many repositories; there is no central tarball that contains all of ROS.

The basic steps for installing ROS are:

- Install the rosdep utility, which is used to resolve ROS dependencies to native packages. This usually comes from pip on non-Ubuntu platforms.
- Install the rosinstall_generator, wstool and rosinstall utilities, which are used to set up ROS workspaces and download the sources for the various ROS packages. These usually come from pip on non-Ubuntu platforms.
- Invoke rosinstall_generator to generate the list of packages to be downloaded.
- Invoke wstool to download and unpack the package sources.
- Invoke rosdep to resolve and install system dependencies
- Invoke catkin to do the build and installation process.

If you're doing the build for a HPC cluster, you'll either want to do the final installation to a shared filesystem (NFS etc) or distribute the resulting installation directory to all of the machines in your cluster.

I believe there are options for rosdep that allow you to query all of the system dependencies for the ROS packages that you're installing; you should be able to use this output to construct a script that installs all of the dependencies on each of your machines.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1